# Has there been an English dub release of Ghost in the Shell - Arise 3?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

Can anyone please tell me if there has there been an English dub release of Ghost in the Shell - Arise 3?

Comment: No official announcement. I assume end this year, if the sales for 1/2 dub where not to horrible.

Comment: Thankyou. Can you please put into an answer so that I may be able to accept it?

Comment: Okay I didn't realise this was off topic.  What do I do know? Remove the question?

Comment: Its been put on hold, you don't necessarily have to do anything. Just be sure to keep it in mind the next time you create a question :)

Answer (score 3):

To clarify, so far there have been no official announcement on [Border OVAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell:_Arise#Films) 3 or 4 in respect to dubbing. Funimation announced on the 8th of March that they aquired the rights to [Arise: Altered Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ghost_in_the_Shell:_Arise_-_Alternative_Architecture_episodes), a recompilation of the four Border OVAs. No word if the dubs or the OVA will continue or if they will just move onto the TV versions, as the dubbed version for 1 and 2 just came out around [mid-May 2015](http://www.funimation.com/blog/2014/05/13/english-recording-set-to-begin-for-ghost-in-the-shell-arise/).

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise this type of question was off topic.